# How to create json object dynamically from UI using values from input fields before sending to API

Tags: arrays, json, angular, rest, api

I have a http.post request which sends an object as a parameter, the expected format is like this:

```
 var searchQuery;
 var subj;
 var body;
 var startDate;
 var endDate;

   {
    "search": {
      "scope": [2,3,32],
      "type": "basic",
       "text": {
              "value": searchQuery, //string variable coming from UI
              "fields": [
                     subj, body     //string variable coming from UI
              ]
       },

      "date": {
        "type": "range",
        "from": startDate,     //string variable coming from UI
        "to": endDate          //string variable coming from UI
      }
```

The problem is some values are optional meaning that if I don't provide searchQuery as a string then the whole key value should be ingnored, e.g "value": searchqery should be not included in the json object if I did not provide value to that variable. Same goes for startDate and endDate if I don't provide values then date shouldbe ignored from the json.
So how to dynamically include or exlude key pair value in the object that coming from UI and how to build that object before sending to a post request?

Whould it be something like this?

```
 var search = {};
 search.text = { value: "", fields: [] };
 {value: "", fields: Array(0)}
 seach.text.value = "wes";
 search.text.value = "wes";
 search.text.fields.push("subject");
 search.text.fields.push("body");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that's a bit more flexible.

```js
var searchQuery = "";
var subj = null;
var body = "";
var startDate = "";
var endDate = null;

let obj = {
  "search": {
    "scope": [2, 3, 32],
    "type": "basic",
    "text": {
      "value": searchQuery, //string variable coming from UI
      "fields": [
        subj, body //string variable coming from UI
      ]
    },

    "date": {
      "type": "range",
      "from": startDate, //string variable coming from UI
      "to": endDate //string variable coming from UI
    }
  }
}

function removeNull(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((res, key) => {
    if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
      // If it's an array, filter out the null items
      res[key] = obj[key].filter((item) => item != null && item !== "");
    } else if (typeof obj[key] === "object" && obj[key] != null) {
      // If it's an object, call the function recursively
      res[key] = removeNull(obj[key]);
    } else if (obj[key] != null && obj[key] !== "") {
      // Otherwise, only add it to the results if it's not null
      res[key] = obj[key];
    }
    return res;
  }, {});
}

console.log(removeNull(obj));
```

Comment: Thank you for help, but it should remove property "value" if its empty "  ". I am still struggling how to implement this

Comment: just a quick one, maybe you can show the same for "fields": [
        subj, body ] if there is no "fields" added subj or body so just empty "fileds" : [] then remove it completly, thanks in advance

Comment: Where we do `res[key] = `, that is where we're adding something to the result. The result of `obj[key].filter` is the array without null elements. All you need to do is check if the array is empty before you add it to the result